# Dúvidas sobre fetch

Tags: javascript, html, .net

Boa tarde galera!
Então, sou novo aqui no stack, é um prazer.

Criei uma api em .net core para estudos, e estou criando um método POST mas ele não funciona de maneira alguma, sequer adiciona ao meu JSON, ele só dá um refresh padrão e com isso, volta do zero com os json já adicionado em minha api!

O meu método não funciona de forma alguma.

Enfim, a solicitação não funciona. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Método Get funciona normalmente, tanto que eu peguei os dados da minha api e retornei.

> //Rota está assim por causa do CORS, mas funciona normalmente.

Para eu adicionar uma pessoa via postman através do JSON: https://localhost:5000/Pessoa via post.

```
fetch('/Pessoa/BuscarTodos').then(
res => {
    res.json().then(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
            if(data.length > 0)
            {
                var temp = "";
                data.forEach((u) => {
                    temp += "<tr>";
                    temp += "<td>"+u.nome+"<td>";
                    temp += "<td>"+u.cpf+"<td>";
                    temp += "<td>"+u.dataNascimento+"<td>";
                    temp += "<td>"+u.uf+"<td>";
                })
                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = temp;
            }
        })            
})
```

Método POST:

```
 document.getElementById('cadastrar').addEventListener('submit',

 function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();


let nome = document.getElementById('Nome').value;
let cpf = document.getElementById('CPF').value;
let dataNascimento = document.getElementById('DataNascimento').value;
let uf = document.getElementById('UF').value;

fetch('Pessoa', {
    Method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers(),
    body: JSON.stringify({"nome": nome, "cpf": cpf, "dataNascimento": dataNascimento, "uf" : uf})
}).then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => console.log(data))
.catch((erro) => console.log('erro', erro));

 })
```

Agora o HTML:

```
<form id="postdata">
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <label for="nome">Nome</label>
    <input type="text" id="Nome" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
    <input type="text" id="CPF" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite seu CPF">
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <label for="dataNascimento">Data de nascimento</label>
    <input type= "date" id="DataNascimento" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua data de nascimento">
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <label for="uf">UF</label>
    <input type="number" id="UF" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a sua unidade federativa">
</div>

<tr></tr>
<div class="botaoCadastrar text-center">
    <button id="cadastrar">
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger">
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: A propriedade `method` deveria ser escrita com `m` minusculo.

Comment: Não resolveu :/

Comment: Você vai ter que dar mais detalhes desse erro. Já abriu as ferramentas de desenvolvedor no seu navegador para visualizar se houve alguma exceção? Já verificou se a requisição foi bem sucedida na sua aba de `network`? Sem esses detalhes não tem como te ajudar, visto que não tem como reproduzir seu problema sem acesso a essa rota.

Comment: Consegui mano! Era porque meu form não tinha o method=post.
Agora ele me retorna um 404 ao fazer a solicitação.